# how can i pass date time in this function for unit testing usin c#

Tags: c#

this the function i am trying to xunit test, i am new in testing. dont want to change this function

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(System.DateTime);
        }
```

i tried

```
 System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
```

but cant pass this as argument

```
public void testfo()
        {
            System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
CanConvert(dateTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method parameter type is Type. Just try to pass method parameter like this:

```
public void testfo()
{
    System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
    CanConvert(dateTime.GetType());

}
```

Comment: This will fail to compile with the error being `'dateTime' is a variable but is used like a type`, instead do `CanConvert(dateTime.GetType())`

Comment: I have edited it. Try like this  CanConvert(dateTime.GetType())